# Resend message on refreshing the page in ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've created a form to send message for admin, and when I click on send button all things are fine and data are sent and saved to the database and I print success message. But if I refresh the page -by pressing <kbd>F5</kbd>- the message is sent again to the server and database!. How can I fix this problem ?

I just want to send message to the server once when I click on send button, not on refresh page.

my code is

```
<asp:Button ID="btnsenddata" runat="server" OnClientClick="return validate()" OnClick="btnsenddata_Click" Text="SendData" />



        protected void btnsenddata_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

           //this place i connect to DB

        }
```

Comment: can you show some code?

Comment: @israelaltar i put my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a commond issue. The behavior is by design: The information of the
button that was pressed is actually re-sent to the server (along with all
other information of the controls) when the page is being refreshed.
A nice way of workaround i found, while surfing the net, is (this way is on the server side) to use HashTable:

```
//Class member   
HashTable ht = new HashTable();

btnMyButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      ht =(Hashtable)Application["UserOKHashtable"]
      if ((ht.ContainsKey(Session["UserSessionKey"]))            
        {
          // double - clicked or user pressed refresh
          return;
        }
        else
        {
         (ht.Add(Session["UserSessionKey"],UserName);
        // your code here
        // and finally
        ((Hashtable)Application["UserOKHashtable"])
         .Remove(Session["UserSessionKey"]);
        }
       }
```

Remember to remove the user's session key from the hashtable at the end
of the procedure, otherwise the user will only be able to click the
button once during the whole session.

If you search for "prevent double post", you will find more information and possible workaround for it.

hope it'll help :)

Comment: thank you for your help ,ist very good help, but when ir run your code i get this error System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.  from this code if (((Hashtable)Application["UserOKHashtable"])
Line 36:             .ContainsKey(Session["UserSessionKey"]))
Line 37:             {

Answer (score 0):

I would put a `OnClick` handler on the button.  So, in your .asp file `<asp:Button id="btnMyButton" runat="server" OnClick="btnMyButton_Click"`

Then on the aspx.cs side you add method 'btnMyButton_Click' and put your code in there

```
btnMyButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   //your code to update database goes here
}
```

Comment: thank you for yout help, i update my post and put my code there, i do like your way but i have same problem

Answer (score 0):

You will have to come up with some method, probably in the database, to ensure that repeated messages are not sent within a certain period of time. You can't easily get around the F5 issue because all that does is tell the browser to repeat exactly what it did the last time. This means the same data is sent to the user. That is the trick, any check you put in must store the data within the server since the client will just replay the last action.

You could hold a session variable to let you know when the user sent this form last (just ensure you check for Session["sentform"] != null when checking for the session variable)

Also, you could create a simple log in the database to say what user clicked (if you have logged in users), the time it was last sent, and something that will let you identify which page, message requestor was fired. Then you can ask the database if this user has sent message for page/process X within the last couple minutes and return true or false.